# Need of a thread listing software for studying mathematics

Tags: support, feature-request

There is been a considerable amount of questions on the mainsite relating to softwares used in plotting in complex functions. [Search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=plot%20complex%20function)

[image]

As a solution to remove the amount of redundancy on the site, I suggest we create some software recommendation thread similar to the resource recommendation thread on [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/resource-recommendations).

Comment: Could you provide some more concrete data? 807 questions is not a lot for the site's current standards. For example, there are 46,656 questions at the moment tagged [complex-analysis] so 807 is not even 2% of the total.

Comment: I have edited the wording. What I mean is that this particular type of thread would be helpful for a number of people who use this site.

Comment: Are you asking about something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985

Comment: Yes, something around those lines @ACB

Comment: I think a big-list for this purpose is a fine idea, and, @Pedro, if it gets only 5% of 807 contributions to the big-list, it will be well worth it.